# How to add hyperlinks to points in a dataset on a graph

Tags: plotting, hyperlink

Is it possible to add hyperlinks to a plot? As in, If I have a list of points and I want to link each of those points to a different reference which can be clicked and opened. Is it do-able?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ListPlot[Table[Hyperlink[{i, i}, "http://www.wolfram.com"], {i, 2}]]
```

yielding the plot

[image]

The plot itself and each its point opens the Wolfram site by click.

This example shows how to create the plot in which different points open different sites.

```
ListPlot[{Hyperlink[{1, 1}, "http://www.wolfram.com"], 
  Hyperlink[{2, 2}, "https://www.google.de/"]}]
```

If you need to open a notebook or to pass to a certain cell within the present notebook, the technique is the same. Have a look at `Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Hyperlink`.

You might also think about wrapping the point by the `Button` command. The button may be made such that the button itself is invisible, only the point being visible. The button may activate opening a file, calling the necessary cite, showing the desired value, and other actions of your wish.

Have fun!

Comment: This method works but when I export the plot as pdf or copy the plot in lets say powerpoint, the hyperlinks don't work anymore. Is there some way to make the hyperlinks work even when exported?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible. hyperlink in a notebook is a functionality of Mma. I do not think that it survives the transformation nb->pdf. It will work after transformation nb->cdf, however.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a hyperlink with `Callout`.

```
ListPlot[{{2.5, 1.7} (*other pts*)
  , Callout[{1, 1}
   , Hyperlink[Style["\[WolframLanguageLogo]", Red, 18, Bold], 
    URL["www.wolfram.com"]], Above]
  , Callout[{2, 2}
   , Hyperlink[Style["Wordle", Gray, 12], 
    URL["https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html"]], Above]
  }
 , PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 3}, {-0.2, 2.5}}
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know about the callout feature. I had a stupid question though, What is the way to selectively change the shape and color of each point in list plot? Let's say I want the first point to be a black square and the second point to be a red circle etc.?

Comment: Please start a fresh question. I think you can do this with `PlotMarkers` although these are assigned to an entire set of points. Transposing the lists and assigning separate markers would do the trick. There are, always, many ways to do anything in Mma.

Answer (score 3):

Combining with [`Tooltip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)

```
f[x_] := 4*x - 4*x^2 - x^3 + x^4

xmin = -2.5; xmax = 2.5;

roots = Solve[{f[x] == 0, xmin <= x <= xmax}, x, Reals];

argmax = Solve[{f'[x] == 0, f''[x] < 0, xmin <= x <= xmax}, x];

argmin = Solve[{f'[x] == 0, f''[x] > 0, xmin <= x <= xmax}, x];

Legended[
 Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2],
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Green,
    Hyperlink[
       Tooltip[Point[{x, f[x]}], {x, f[x]}] /. N[#],
       "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function"] & /@ 
     roots,
    Blue,
    Hyperlink[
       Tooltip[Point[{x, f[x]}], {x, f[x]}] /. N[#],
       "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima"] & /@
     argmin,
    Red,
    Hyperlink[
       Tooltip[Point[{x, f[x]}], {x, f[x]}] /. N[#],
       "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima"] & /@
     argmax}],
 PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"local maximum", "root", 
   "local minimum"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This method works but when I export the plot as pdf or copy the plot in lets say powerpoint, the hyperlinks don't work anymore. Is there some way to make the hyperlinks work even when exported?